# thumbnail scroller margin(padding) issue

Tags: html, css, thumbnails

I want to  add a padding-right(margin-right) on each thumbnail but the problem is that the last thumbnails are disappearing.
So, my question is how to add a decent padding (margin) on those thumbnails without disappearing.
This is the [link](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_thumbnail_scroller.html).

Comment: It would help if you could add your html & js code.

Comment: put up an example on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com

Comment: I've edited my post ! Check now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways:

- CSS n-th child selectors to target nth thumbnail and give it a zero `margin-right`
- If the thumbnails are in a row of their own then you can use the CSS `:last` property

The above is perfect if you're supporting modern browsers.

If you have to support older browsers then you will manually have to add a class to the last thumbnail in a row. eg. `.last-thumb` and use that in your CSS to zero the margin.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided very much information, but if your thumbnails are disappearing then it sounds like:

1. Your container isn't big enough to hold the thumbnails.
2. Your container is set to `overflow:hidden` whereas it should be set to `overflow:visible`.

Comment: If I set overflow:visible  a big browser  horizontal scroll appears and I don't want this. Check the example,I've edited my post.